# I need to access TabPage before removing TabControl

Tags: c#, events, tabcontrol, tabpage

In main program I add TabPage (UserControl) to TabControl. This Control has few data I would like to have before removing it. 
When using  TabControl.RemoveControl the sender is TabControl, and I cannot access the TabPage because I don't know which one is it (using TabControl.TabPages.Count I know that my Tab ain't remove yet so I can access it).

Is there any Event for TabControl to mark TabPage that is going to be removed? or any other idea.

Basically: I add tabpage with editing of some MySql data, and after closing i would like check is there was a Edit on that row (via bool wasEdited) and if it was edited i would like to read the id of that row. If the form for editing wasn't in seperate file i would just run method on that, and I can't use static method to access non static DataGridView to update row.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: @MikroDel, I agree that usually people should show their code, but the OP had written what he had tried and where he is having problems. I doubt that a code sample would do any difference in this case.

Comment: @LarsKristensen yes it depends. For the most of people the best combination to unserstand the question is text + code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in event handler `TabControl.ControlRemoved` you have `ControlEventArgs  e`. Control that's being removed is `e.Control`.

Comment: Yeah, i figure it out but you are 100% correct, sadly I didn't refresh this page before figuring it out. I manage to make this code: ((MY_User_Control)(((TabControl)sender).TabPages[e.Control.Name].Controls[0])).wasEdited this way im checking what i want :-) Thanks alot

Comment: @MichałPółrolniczak, You are fetching the TabPage from the TabControl.TabPages collection, by using the name of the actual TabPage you get from e.Control. This is not wrong, but it is a little bit redundant. You could just do:
((MY_User_Control)((TabPage)e.Control).Controls[0]).wasEdited

Comment: @LarsKristensen, I readed that in Event Triger sender is the object that triggerd event, and EventArgs (e) is only passthough data - I didnt know that the data could be an object, in this case TabPage. Your code worked. In this case that e is actualy an OBJECT that being removed from Parent which is sender, thank my code really is redundant :-) Thanks for making me learn something today :-)

Comment: @MichałPółrolniczak, no problem - happy to help :)
A rule of thumb I usually use; If the EventArgs are anything other than simply "EventArgs", then there is usually something useful in the arguments. In your case, "ControlEventArgs" contained exactly what you needed.